# Callback hell, pyramid of doom, node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, promise

I am new to node, after I finished my APIs I realized that all of them are a mess, and are a callback hell, this forced me to learn about promises, now it was all good until I faced an API that has condition with more than possible function, my question is how to do nested promises, my code is about a parent object who has a user attached to it, when delete route is called there are many conditions:

1. if this parent has children attached to it it shouldn't be deleted
2. no children

   a. this parent is in more than one school, the school_id is removed from the       school id of the parent object and the user object attached to it

   b. if this parent has no children and only on school_id it should be removed and the user attached also should be removed

The code looks like this and it's 100% functional

```
router.post('/delete',Validation, function (req, res) {
var school_id = req.body.schoolId;
var parent_id = req.body.selected[0];
/
Student.findOne({parent_ids:parent_id},function(err,parentF){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.json({status:"error",message:"an error occurred"});
        return
    }else if(parentF){
        res.json({status:"error", message:"you can not delete a parent who has students associated with it"});
        return;
    }else{
        Parent.findOne({_id:parent_id},function(err,parent){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                res.json({status:"error",message:"an error occurred"});
                return;
            }else{
                if(parent.school_id.length>1){
                    var a = parent.school_id.indexOf(school_id);
                    parent.school_id.pop(a);
                    parent.save(function(err,parent){
                        if(err){
                            console.log(err);
                            res.json({status:"error",message:"an error occurred"});
                            return;
                        }else{
                            User.findOne({refid:parent_id},function(err,user){
                                if(err){
                                    console.log(err);
                                    res.json({status:"error",message:"an error occurred"});
                                    return;
                                }else {
                                    user.school_id.pop(a);
                                    user.save(function(err) {
                                        if(err){
                                            console.log(err);
                                            res.json({status:"error",message:"an error occurred"});
                                            return;
                                        }else{
                                            res.json({status: "success", message: "parent removed"});
                                            return;
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    Parent.remove({_id: parent_id}, function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            res.json({status: "error", message: err.message});
                        } else {
                            User.remove({refid:parent_id},function(err){
                                if (err) {
                                    res.json({status: "error", message: "parent user wasn't deleted"});
                                    return;
                                }else{
                                    res.json({status: "success", message: "parent data successfully deleted"});
                                    return;
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
});
```

I am trying to apply promises and make my code better.

Sorry about the long question but i've hit a wall any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: what is your node version?

Comment: node version is 4.2

Comment: `trying to apply promises` - where? `but i've hit a wall` - before even trying!! there's no use of promises in that code at all

Comment: ok how do i avoid the callback hell am in, async or any usable method, whats the suitable way of doing it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on codereview

Answer (score 2):

create some "promise" flavoured functions for findOne, remove and save

```
let findOneP = (object, params) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    object.findOne(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            return reject(err);
        }
        resolve(data);
    });
});
let removeP = (object, params) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    object.remove(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            return reject(err);
        }
        resolve(data);
    });
});
let saveP = (object) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    object.save((err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            return reject(err);
        }
        resolve(data);
    });
});
```

The above can be done easier with Bluebird Promisify, but as you haven't specified bluebird, then I just used a quick and dirty promise wrapper

Then use promise chains to make life easy

```
router.post('/delete',Validation, function (req, res) {
    var school_id = req.body.schoolId;
    var parent_id = req.body.selected[0];

    findOneP(Student, {parent_ids: parent_id})
    .then(parentF => {
        if (parentF) {
            throw "you can not delete a parent who has students associated with it";
        }
    })
    .then(() => findOneP(Parent, {_id: parent_id}))
    .then(parent => {
        if (parent.school_id.length > 1) {
            var a = parent.school_id.indexOf(school_id);
            parent.school_id.pop(a);
            return saveP(parent)
                .then(parent => findOneP(User, {refid: parent_id}))
                .then(user => saveP(user))
                .then(() => "parent removed");
        }
        return removeP(Parent,{_id: parent_id})
            .then(() => removeP(User, {refid: parent_id}))
            .then(() => "parent data successfully deleted");
    })
    .then(message => res.json({status: "success",message}))
    .catch(message => res.json({status: "error",message}));
});
```

I just read that you use node 4.2 - you may need to

1. run this through a transpiler like [babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/)
2. load a Promise library, like [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html)

If using bluebird, use it's promisify functions instead of "manually" promisifying